# Why isn't my readFileSync function executing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to read from a file in Node.  Here is my code:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var fs = require('fs');
var path = process.argv[2];

var glossArr = []

fs.readFileSync(path, {encoding: "utf8"}, function (err, markup){
    console.log('function executing')
    if (err) throw err;
    const $ = cheerio.load(markup);
    var glossar = $('body').children().last();
    var index = $('body').children().last().prev();


    glossar.children().children().children().each(function(i, elem) {
    var obj = {};
        var container = $(this).children();

    var unter = container.children();
    var begriff = unter.first().text();
    var text = unter.last().text();
    obj[begriff] = text;
    obj['file'] = path;
    glossArr.push(obj)
    });    

});

console.log('done reading file...')

var glossString = JSON.stringify(glossArr)
var result = 'export default ' + glossString

fs.writeFileSync('./data/data.js', result)
```

For some reason, the readFileSync doesn't execute at all.  The only thing that's logged is 'done reading file...'

However, when I changed it to `readFile()` (instead of sync), the function executes and works as expected.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`readFileSync` doesn't accept a callback parameter because it's synchronous. You need to change your code to move the code from within the callback to beneath the synchronous function:

```
var markup = fs.readFileSync(path, {encoding: "utf8"});
const $ = cheerio.load(markup);
// ...
```

To clarify, the `readFileSync` *is* being executed, it's just that you aren't doing anything with the result and your callback parameter is being ignored.

Comment: An opinion: You seem to have a grasp of async code & callbacks, which is the encouraged method of programming in Node. You might want to just stick with that instead of changing the method to synchronous

Comment: In this particular case, it's really not needed, but I usually would

Comment: Of course, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

**fs.readFileSync** Synchronous version of **fs.readFile()**. Returns the contents of the path
Once the content is returned you can perform the task you want to do.
for more understanding use the following link [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readsync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position)