# Node.js - Cannot append global variable when using fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

Im trying to read multiple xml files and parse data from them and i managed to do that but now new problem appeared.

allData variable is never changed, no matter what i do. What am i supposed to do here?

I dont know what to do or what to try, this is my first time working with files and im honestly surprised ive managed to come this far.

```js
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

var fs = require('fs')
var allData = {
    store: []
}

function readFiles(__dirname, onFileContent, onError) {


    fs.readdir(__dirname + '\\parse\\', function (err, filenames) {
            if (err) {
                return;
            }


            filenames.forEach(function (filename) {


                    console.log(filename)
                    fs.readFile(__dirname + '\\parse\\' + filename, 'utf-8', function (err, content) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err)
                                return;
                            }
                            parseString(content, function (err, result) {

                                let tempObj = {}

                                let data = result.storeD[0]
                                

                                if (data.name) {
                                    tempObj['name'] = data.name[0];
                                }

                                if (data.price) {

                                    tempObj['price'] = data.price[0];
                                }


                                //more of the same type of code

                                console.log(tempObj)
                                //output: { name: 'Data1', price: '1000' }

                                allData.store.push(tempObj)

                            })


                        })

                        

                    })


            });

            console.log("All data: ",allData)
            //Outputs once at the begining 
            //output: All data:  { store: [] }


    }
    

readFiles(__dirname)
```

### SOLVED

adjusted code to use`.readFileSync()`(removed callback function) and now it works.

```js
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

var fs = require('fs')
var allData = {
    store: []
}

function readFiles(__dirname, onFileContent, onError) {


    fs.readdir(__dirname + '\\parse\\', function (err, filenames) {
            if (err) {
                return;
            }


            filenames.forEach(function (filename) {


                    console.log(filename)
                    let file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '\\parse\\' + filename, 'utf-8')
                            parseString(file, function (err, result) {

                                let tempObj = {}

                                let data = result.storeD[0]
                                

                                if (data.name) {
                                    tempObj['name'] = data.name[0];
                                }

                                if (data.price) {

                                    tempObj['price'] = data.price[0];
                                }


                                //more of the same type of code

                                console.log(tempObj)
                                //output: { name: 'Data1', price: '1000' }

                                allData.store.push(tempObj)

                            })


                        

                        

                    })

                    console.log("All data: ",allData)
            });

            
            //Outputs once at the begining 
            //output: All data:  { store: [] }


    }
    

readFiles(__dirname)
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: I think it does, you are probably logging to console before async file read finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.readdir()` and `.readFile()` methods are async, so in fact the `console.log()` is executed before all of the `readFile` operations.

In order to access the `allData` variable after these operations are complete, you have to either make them sync using `.readFileSync()` instead or you need to promisify the `.readFile()` method and wait for all of the promises to resolve.

Comment: I tried using .readFileSync but then i dont get any output at all. Ill try to read up on those other things.

Comment: Just a heads up, node.js now has promise based FS module, to save you having to promisify.   https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45191380/14048292 - This comment made me realize .readFileSync ignores callback, after adjusting my code i managed to get it work. Main post updated.